# How to prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(k-1)!(u-k)!} =0$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How to prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} =0$?

My approach : I have proved that it equals to 0 when n is even but can't solve it when n is odd. How to prove this when n is odd?

Comment: Use the Binomial expansion of $(1-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: Note: it is true only when $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use binomial theorem

$$ 0=(1-1)^{n-1} = (n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$$